# Read and write Sharepoint Lists from external HTML/Javascript programs

Tags: javascript, rest, web, sharepoint

I am trying to access (Basically get the list items and update the list items from/to) sharepoint externally through my website. Is there a way where I can do it ?
I got CORS error when trying it from REST API, on digging deeper I found couple of resources saying it is not possible.

If there is any, my Sharepoint list just has 2 columns. Also how to specify colums and URL of my shrepoint site?

Comment: if it's an in-house instance of SP...you'll need to update the SP web.config...Access-Control-Allow-Origin...not specific to 2013...https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9ae5ea28-5e46-4192-953d-d6142b1d060a/cors-change-in-sharepoint-server-2016?forum=SP2016

Answer (score 0):

Outside of SharePoint, it's suggested to use SharePoint CSOM to handle SharePoint list item data due to Cross Domain issue:

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

Comment: But I don't think it can be used in a web browser, or is there a way to enable it ?

Comment: You can create a ASP.NET Web Form Application, in code behind use CSOM code to handle list data. In front-end, place some textbox control for user enter value.